# Firefox textarea columns are different than attribute value

Tags: html, css, firefox

On a website I made, I have a textarea like this:

```
<textarea maxlength="1240" rows="20" cols="60" name="sub" style="color: #a7c1c5; background: black;"></textarea>
```

Only on Firefox, this textarea has a visible 62 columns instead of 60. This causes issues in my website, because I need the text to fit perfectly within the textarea. This causes other browsers like Chrome or Opera to display the text incorrecty. How do I force the textarea to be 60 columns on all browsers no matter what?

Oddly, rows are not affected.

I have some CSS modifying the padding as well, but the issue still happens.

[Here is a jsfiddle demoing the issue, error only happens in Firefox](https://jsfiddle.net/q2zxh8gy/2/)

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33654 :(

Comment: While not the most elegant, would it be possible to make an exception for Firefox to have only 58 columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly it's been a while for that firefox bug, you'd have to detect user agent and adjust cols value via JS.

```js
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1) {
   document.querySelector('#myTextarea').cols = '58';
}
```

```html
<textarea id="myTextarea" placeholder="wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwAs you can see, this is 62 w's instead of 60" maxlength="1240" rows="20" cols="60" name="sub" style="color: #a7c1c5; background: black;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Well, after someone's comment stating about it being a bug, I did some experiementation. I essentially added a width of 60ch and a height of 40ch in the style attribute, and it worked. There is a large blank space at the bottom on chrome however, but that isn't that much of a deal. I am going to wait until there are some more answers, maybe ones not involving JS, which is one of the goals of my site.